# CodeIgniter 3 pretty date and time format

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter, datetime

I have made a **Register and Login Application** with CodeIgniter 3 and Bootstrap.

I am showing all the users in a view:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="col-md-1">ID</th>
      <th class="col-md-3">Full name</th>
      <th class="col-md-6">Email</th>
      <th class="col-md-4">Date created</th>
      <th class="col-md-4">Date updated</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($users as $user): ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $user->id ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $user->fname . " " . $user->lname; ?></td>
      <td><a href="maitlo:<?php echo $user->email; ?>"><?php echo $user->email; ?></a></td>
      <td><?php echo $user->created_at ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $user->updated_at ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I want the *Date created* and *Date updated* columns to be formatted nicely: **March 10 2001, at 15:16:03**.

I have loaded the date helper.

What shall I write *in the view* to get a "pretty" date and time format like that mentioned above?

Comment: you should read through this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: I am interested in Codeigniter _specific_  ways to get pretty date and/or time formats, since there is a _date  helper_ that I have loaded.

Comment: read this: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/date_helper.html#mdate

Comment: it's all written there !!! I'm not copying the documentation example as an answer.

Comment: How did you save the date in the db table, is it with php time or db , or show an example of what is returned from $user->updated_at

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this way

Example only

```
<?php echo date('M d Y');?> at <?php echo date('H:i:s', strtotime('15:16:03'));?>
```

Prints

January 14 2018 at 15:16:03

Answer (score 0):

A full, pretty date and time format **Sunday, Nov 19, 2017 at 00:34:36** will be output by writing:

```
<?php echo nice_date($user->created_at, 'l, M d, Y') . ' at '.  nice_date($user->created_at, 'H:i:s'); ?>
```

And **Nov 19, 2017 at 00:34:36** will be output by writing:

```
<?php echo nice_date($user->created_at, 'M d, Y') . ' at '.  nice_date($user->created_at, 'H:i:s'); ?>
```